# Best way to save a 2D Pygame platformer level tile map with extra data

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer using my own engine in Python/Pygame and have made a good start. I've also made a level designer that exports the level tile map and the game imports it, but I need to associate different things, like switches that open specific doors (or to be more precise, pressure plates that hold a specific door open) but my tile map array currently only holds the tile image index number. What's the best way to include associated tiles (like which switch opens which door etc)?

Do I make an extra file with that data? Or do I have 2 values for each tile? I've tried Googling, but it's not really covered anywhere. I'm sure there's someone with this kind of experience out there... I don't really want to hard-code it in as I want the game to be as versatile as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your file format from storing one tile index per 2D cell to storing some more complex data object.  My first thought would be a dictionary per cell for maximum flexibility moving forward, but serializing that and storing it will be quite large.  There's a trade-off here between flexibility and storage size.

Another option would be using NamedTuples to store a fixed number of parameters per cell, while preserving a concise serialization.  NamedTuples are nice because they let you very concisely represent a data object in a way that both serializes well and can be queried into using named fields.

The questions you need to ask yourself are "what metadata do I need to know about each cell on the map" and "how much do I care about concise file size to represent them".

Comment: that's fantastic! I was toying with the idea of using dictionaries but I wasn't aware of NamedTuples which sounds like the way to go here. After looking into this datatype, it sounds like a perfect fit for what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, could I not just use a normal tuple for each cell? On second thoughts, I'm thinking NamedTuples might be overkill if I just need the image ID number and a set of coords for each cell. For example, the cell that contains the pressure_plate which I need linked to a specific door, could I use something like (8, 20, 20) for example? Or even (8, (20, 20)) if a tuple can contain another tuple?

Comment: `level_data = [[(0, 0, 0) for x in range(grid_width)] for y in range(grid_height)]`

Comment: Oh no, tuples are immutable. Nuts.

Comment: Tuples might be immutable, but you can always just replace the location in the 2D grid with a new tuple.  I like using NamedTuples for most things because it adds context to which element means what, which you'll really appreciate after you spend 6 hours debugging a problem that boils down to accessing the wrong element of that tuple. Also it's common practice to do things like this in list comprehensions `[[(0, 0, 0) for _ in range(grid_width)] for _ in range(grid_height)]` when you don't actually need the variables `x` and `y`.

Comment: How would I apply NamedTuples to my list comprehension though? Do I have to give a physical name to each instance (i.e. cell)? Or could I just iterate through like I'm doing? I've seen a couple of examples, but not in this context.

Comment: You just replace your tuple literal `(0, 0, 0)` with a NamedTuple instance.  You can then replace them with meaningful instances like normal.
`
>>> Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender')
>>> people = [Person(name='', age=0, gender='') for _ in range(3)]
>>> people
[Person(name='', age=0, gender=''), Person(name='', age=0, gender=''), Person(name='', age=0, gender='')]`

Comment: This works, but it's only creating 1 row. Do I have the syntax right? `Cell = collections.namedtuple('Cell', ['image_id', 'linked_x', 'linked_y']) >>> Cells = [[Cell(image_id=0, linked_x=0, linked_y=0) for _ in range(grid_width)] for _ in range(grid_height)]`

Comment: The thing is, I'm not dealing with bunch of people, I have a grid of 2,625 cells that I need to refer to by where the mouse cursor is on the screen, like I do with my current array. How would I refer to NamedTuples if they're all called one name?

Comment: That syntax is creating a 2D array as needed, what are the values for `grid_width` and `grid_height`? And I don't understand the second question.  You refer to them by their indices in the grid.  `cells[x][y]` is a different Cell than `cells[a][b]` (assuming `x,y` != `a,b`).  Their "name" is their index pair into the grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173986/discussion-between-jasonpy-and-bowlinghawk95).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was posted by @BowlingHawk95 as using NamedTuples for the data object which enabled me to add multiple fields for each cell. I wanted to post a sample to show the resulting code, and a snap shot of how I've implemented it to help anybody else looking for the same thing.

```
# Initialise the level data array with NamedTuples;
# 'linked_point' is a tuple (x, y) for an associated cell - e.g. switch associated with a door:
Cell = namedtuple('Cell', ['image_id', 'linked_point'])
level_data = [[Cell(image_id=0, linked_point=(0, 0)) for _ in range(grid_width)] for _ in range(grid_height)]
```

And now that I am able to add coordinates (as the `linked_point`) I can now reference another cell from the one I'm on. The following image shows a shot of my level designer, with the coords in the title bar, and also showing the image_id name and coords of the linked cell.

[image: Level Designer Linked Points]

Massive thanks to @BowlingHawk95 for the assistance!